# How to encapsulate the statements and use it in Order by Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to encapsulate this case statements and make my query short, since i need to generate report using multiple temp tables. I donot want to use the case statement every where.

```
Select * from #SumED_DB 
order by case  
when [type] = 'Within 30 days' then 1
when [type] = 'Within 60 days' then 2
when [type] = 'Within 90 days' then 3
when [type] = 'Within 120 days' then 4
when [type] = 'Greater than 120 days' then 5
when [type] = 'Blank' then 6
else 7
end
```

How do I resolve this issue? I know function will help me, but how will i achieve it?

I want my  query to look like:

```
select * from #SumED_DB order by (function);
```

I Have used a table and joined it and then have used order by clause.
How can I do this using function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than creating a lookup table to join to for your ordering, I think the function or repeating code are your only other options.  In general you want to avoid calling functions though, as not only will they produce a separate call for each row, [they also prohibit parallelism](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx) which will degrade your query performance.

If your dataset will always be a small summary table - as this looks to be from your naming conventions and requirements - this will probably not be that big of a trade off.

To create your function:

```
create function dbo.usp_TypeOrder (@Type nvarchar(100))
returns int
as
begin
return (select case @Type  
                when 'Within 30 days' then 1
                when 'Within 60 days' then 2
                when 'Within 90 days' then 3
                when 'Within 120 days' then 4
                when 'Greater than 120 days' then 5
                when 'Blank' then 6
                else 7
                end
        )
end;
```

and to use it in your query:

```
select *
from #SumED_DB
order by dbo.usp_TypeOrder([type]);
```

Comment: Performance Wise which option Should I Go for, Joining another table that has the sequence i need or the above function ?

Comment: Performance Wise which option Should I Go for, Joining another table that has the sequence i need or the above function ?

Comment: @Ruchi  You will need to test this on your own environment, create both and see which performs better.  If you don't know what to look for, I would strongly advise you read through the info here: https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/  particularly section 2.